# Java generic method declaration fundamentals

Tags: java, generics, declaration

I'm starting to learn `Generics`for `Java` and I read several tutorials, but I'm a bit confused and not sure how a generic method is declared.

When I use a generic type, what is the correct order to define the method? I found this sample, when do I need to use the angle brackets and when not?

```
public class Box<A> {

    private A a;
    ...

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public <A> List<A> transform(List<A> in) {
        return null;
    }

    public static <A> A getFirstElement(List<A> list) {
        return null;
    }

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your code is using the same character A, but it has *several* different "meanings" in the different places:

```
public class Box<T> {
```

braces required, because you are saying here: Box uses a generic type, called T.

**Usages** of T go without braces:

```
private T a;
public void setA(T a) {
```

But then

```
public <T2> List<T2> transform(List<T2> in) {
```

is introducing **another** type parameter. I named it T2 to make it clear that it is **not** the same as T. The idea is that the *scope* of T2 is **only** that one method `transform`. Other methods do not know about T2!

```
public static <A> A getFirstElement(List<A> list) {
```

Same as above - would be "T3" here ;-)

EDIT to your comment: you can't have a **static** method use the class-wide type T. That is simply not possible! See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createStatic) for why that is!

EDIT no.2: the generic allows you to write code that is **generic** (as it can deal with **different** classes); but still given you **compile-time** safety. Example:

```
 Box<String> stringBox = new Box<>();
 Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<>();
 integerBox.add("string"); // gives a COMPILER error!
```

Before people had generics, they could only deal with **Object** all over the place; and manual casting.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand it a bit better. But how would I have to adjust the static method to return the T of the Box class?

Comment: Thank you, most kind of you :) 
One last question, what is the benefit of having a class declared with a generic type, could I have also done something like this?

public class Box() {
   private T t;

  public Box(T t) {
   this.t = t;
}

Comment: Another update for you. But please understand: this is really basic stuff, documented many times out there. You better start reading the Oracle tutorials on generics. The main reason why I am taking so much time to write up answers ... honestly; is me hoping you to accept my answer soon ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much :) I read the tutorials, but I still got a bit confused, thank you for all the help, now it is clear for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Your example shows two different concepts: *generic classes* and *generic methods*

This is a *generic class* introducing a type parameter `<A>`:

```
public class Box<A> {

}
```

While these are *generic methods* introducing their *own* type parameter `<A>`:

```
public <A> List<A> transform(List<A> in) {
    return null;
}

public static <A> A getFirstElement(List<A> list) {
    return null;
}
```

Compare it with a class having a field of a specific name and a method having a parameter of that name:

```
public class Box {
    private String name;

    publix Box(String name) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a requirement in your method where you need to return type is depends on your method parameter at that time you can write angle bracket before method signature as shown in your example, In short, as word suggest Generic is used for feature where same class or utility required to be used for multiple type of objects